# Singleton - Protected vs Private Constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns

When designing singletons, why is the constructor made `protected` and not `private`? This is based on what I've seen over the web.

We want to control the number of instances made of that class, fair enough, but why `protected`? Wouldn't `private` do the trick as well?

Comment: If someone has decided that singletons are a good idea, then you should expect their code to have other nonsensical design decisions, and shouldn't try to learn anything from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using singletons is bad. Period.

That said, the constructor can be private, no problem. But what if you want to derive another singleton from your singleton(as if having one singleton wasn't bad enough)? In that case the derived class needs access to the base singleton constructor.

Comment: but doesn't that let you bypass the singleton property?

Comment: @Jason S: You can bypass pretty much everything. Doesn't mean you should

Comment: @Jason S It can. I don't have my copy of GoF at work, but I believe they point out the potential problems with subclassing a Singleton and might provide alternative options/solutions.

Comment: I really want to +1 this, but singletons aren't bad **in all cases**. They're very often misused but don't hold that against the pattern!

Comment: Let's assume you really need a singleton (I don't care if that's "impossible", let me make my argument). If it lets you bypass the "only one class restriction", wouldn't it be better to just drop the thing and use a global?

Comment: @Yuck: They are easy to code, but in large projects they do tend to mess things up.

Comment: But constructor is not inherited , then what's the difference if we put in the the private ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Ron_s: You're wrong: What is inherited and what is accessible are two different things. Private functions are only accessible in the class, not the derived classes

Comment: Okay , I got you.The Ctor of the base class is needed when creating the the Derived. for example: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
 A() {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
 B() {}
};

int main()

{

 B b;
    return 0;
} // if the Ctor of A was in the private , we won't be able to create a B instance .. thanks Armen :)

Comment: @Ron_s: That's right. I don't understand why you included `<iostream>` in your example though :))))

Comment: I have a ready .cpp file for changes and program-tests , sometimes I use cout and his friends , so I just copy-pasted it (sorry) :)

Comment: @Ron_s: `cout` is definitely female, I object to your presumption of male domination.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, Singletons in the **vast** majority of cases are a bad idea ([Why?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx)). Use them *even less* than global variables.

It's so that subclasses can instantiantiate the Singleton base class, returning it as a part of itself in it's own `GetInstance()`-type function. This is the reason that it is done in *Design Patterns*. Therefore it's only really relevent if you plan on inheriting from the Singleton.

GoF says, (page 130, *Subclassing the Singleton class*);

> A more flexible approach uses a **registry of singletons**. Instead of having `Instance` define the set of possible singleton classes, the singleton classes can register their singleton instance by name in a well-known registry.

In using a registry of singletons, a `protected` constructer in the base Singleton is still required (according to the implementation given)

In short; Make it `protected` if you plan on inheriting from the Singleton. Otherwise, go with `private`.

Comment: @dj aqeel "Globals and singletons are already well-known as a design antipattern" http://neugierig.org/software/chromium/notes/2011/08/static-initializers.html

Comment: @dj: (a) Globally-accessible objects remove structure from the design, making it hard to keep track of dependencies between objects. This makes large projects harder to maintain. (b) Objects that enforce a particular lifetime management make testing harder, as they can't be created and destroyed during a test. Perhaps the `protected` constructor nonsense in this question is an attempt to reduce that effect; a `public` constructor would be better still. (c) The "static initialisation fiasco" and thread-safety issues make them hard to implement correctly in C++03 (although C++0x will fix that).

Answer (score 0):

It's all about inheritance.
`class lazy_singleton: public singleton {};`
 will be the same singleton with singleton constructor